# Initializing a model on button press (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to initialize a model, with properties depending on what button is pressed. The model is then passed to a partial view. The partial view is shown as a modal. Here's what I need it to do:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Students.Models.Student>
@{ 
    Students.Models.Student s;
}

@foreach (var student in Model)
{
<btn class="btn btn-success" id="modBtn">Edit student @Model.id</btn>
// s = student; -- assign model to button
}

@Html.Partial("/Views/Student/_PartialShow.cshtml", s)
```

Here's the js to show the partial view modal:

```
$(function () {
    // Vars
    var modBtn = $('#modBtn'),
        modal = $('#modal'),
        close = modal.find('.close'),
        modContent = modal.find('.modal-content');

    // open modal when click on open modal button 
    modBtn.on('click', function () {
        modal.css('display', 'block');
        modContent.removeClass('modal-animated-out').addClass('modal-animated-in');
    });

    // close modal when click on close button or somewhere out the modal content 
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (target.is(modal) || target.is(close)) {
            modContent.removeClass('modal-animated-in').addClass('modal-animated-out').delay(300).queue(function (next) {
                modal.css('display', 'none');
                next();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way.  The idea is to open the partial view with auto-filled textboxes depending on what button is pressed. And use the ID of the model to call an action with an ID parameter.

This approach works for creating new students, the partial view itself posts successfully but now I just need a way to pass it values.

Comment: So all you are trying to do is open a modal dialog which has data populated about that student from the Id passed  ? You need to make an ajax call to the server passing the Id where you will return the partial view result, which you will use to populate the modal dialog body. I do not see code for anything like that in your question

Comment: I did consider having an action returning the partial view, but would it be possible to still use it as a modal with the javascript functionality? Also I already have the populated model in the view, so I was hoping there's another way of setting the values

Comment: What you mean by you already have it populated in the view. I do not see that in the code you shared in your question! You have to be specific about what your current situation is and what your expected behavior is. It is hard to guess what is in your mind from other other side of the world! :)

Comment: I am iterating over a list of models, and for each one I need to "assign" the model to a button.  So the models are populated, I just need a way to make the button apply the model to "s" in my example.  I updated my example sorry

Comment: You are creating a button with `Id` attribute value `modBtn` inside a loop, which will create more than on button with same Id, which is invalid HTML!  Remove the Id for the button and use a different selector for your jQuery code.

Comment: But the actual problem is, how can I set the model with the button? How would I do `s = student;` depending on which button is pressed as in the example?

Comment: What is **s** ?

Comment: It is a variable in the code I posted  `Students.Models.Student s;`  I'm using it to send to the partial view, but I need the button press to assign it first.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. Store the entire model (list of students) to a js array and when user clicks the button, get the item from the js array and update the input elements in your modal using the item properties. Another option is to send the Id of clicked student to server where it will get the details of the student and return a partial view ( which is the HTLM markup of the inputs with data populated) and update the modal dialog body.